# Community login without redirecting user to Salesforce with SSO or OAuth

Tags: community, single-sign-on, oauth

We are building a Drupal site for one of our customers.

Our customer wants to use the Salesforce self-registration and community login features for authenticating their customers to the CMS.

As far as I know these features use either SSO or OAuth. Our customer wants to have the self-registration and login pages in the CMS, without redirecting the users to Salesforce for some user experience purposes.

I was wondering whether this is possible because as far as I know you need enter your credentials in the authentication provider's domain for both SSO and OAuth.